# Is verification code a scam?

Tags: authentication, malware, facebook, sms, scam

When facebook sends the confirmation code, the name FACEBOOK is not displayed as the sender,, instead phone numbers of different countries. Until now, it was only on my notebook, but today I synced my firefox passwords, history, and bookmarks to my PC, and since then, also on the PC phone numbers appear there instead of the name FACEBOOK. And the messages is spelled incorrectly.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Facebook, and other sites, can send legitimate codes from strange sources with poor spelling.

Comment: Schroeder, thank you very much for your answer! Today I also asked this question in a group called Facebook Support, only hackers answered: asked me to send them a private message and they will solve it.